# VBA code to run sub routine in any column based on value in cell A

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use a Do Until to run down a column of data (could be any column across the worksheet) and perform certain tasks based on the value in column A.

Column A results are either 1, 2 or END!? I want to run down any column and perform a routine based on the value in A until the value in A = "END!?"

I can't use the offset function as the Do Until will move across a column each month.

Basically I need the code to always check the value in column A and do one of three functions depending on the value and my mind has gone a complete blank!

---

I already have the full Do Until code written, and the sub routines to run depending on what is in there.

I just cant get the looking at the value in column A part right!

Comment: Show us your code otherwise we can't guess what you have tried.

Comment: 'Do Until VALUEIN COLUMN A = "END!?"
        'If  VALUE IN COLUMN A = 1 Then
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else
        Selection.Copy
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        End If
        Loop

Comment: Sorry, that didn't paste well! All I'm attempting to do is go down each row in a column and paste a formula over itself as a value if column A contains a 2. If it contains a 1 I want to keep the formula.

Comment: It's at the VALUE IN COLUMN A part that I can be in any column across the worksheet based on an earlier search to find the month I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select Case` :

```
Dim LastRow As Double
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim i As Double

Set wS = thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Sheet Name
With wS
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .rows.Count).End(xlup).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        Select Case .Cells(i,1).Value
            Case Is = 1
                Call SubProc1
            Case Is = 2
                Call SubProc2
            Case Is = "END!?"
                Call SubProcEND
            Case Else
                MsgBox "Value : " & Criteria1 & " not handled!", _
                        vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Case not handled"
        End Select
    Next i
End With 'wS
```